# Extract text from each line from a multiple-line text file based on a condition, Linux

Tags: linux, unix

I have a txt file with only one column that each line represent a different fastq.gz file from a sequence output. See an example below:

```
36108-ABZG339L_S237_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
36108-ABZG339L_S237_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
36108-ABZGM_S7_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
36108-ABZGM_S7_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

First of all, I would like to convert the first "-" symbol to underscore "_".

I achieved that through the following command:

```
sed 's/[-]/_/Ig' inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt
```

Then the outputfile.txt is:

```
36108_ABZG339L_S237_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
36108_ABZG339L_S237_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
36108_ABZGM_S7_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
36108_ABZGM_S7_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

Afterwards, I would like to extract in a new txt file only the text between first and second underscore, so:

```
ABZG339L
ABZG339L
ABZGM
ABZGM
```

How can I achieve? I tried through sed, awk but I cannot find out.

Thanks on advance for your aid,

Magí

Comment: You need not to perform first substitution and then printing, you can do it in a single shot itself by using different field separator option in `awk` or other programming languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***1st solution:*** To get your shown expected sample output you need not to first substitute `-` to `-` and then print, we can use power of `awk` here to create multiple field separators and then print needed value accordingly.

```
awk -F'-|_' '{print $2}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation of above `awk` program would be, making `_` and `-` as field separators for whole Input_file then printing 2nd field/column in it.

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Using `sed` solution, using `sed`'s back reference capability here.

```
sed -E 's/^[^-]*-([^_]*).*/\1/' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Using `sed`'s `-E` option here to enable ERE(extended regular expression) here. In main program of `sed` then from starting of value till 1st occurrence of `-` matching it and then creating 1st back reference(temp location in memory to be retrieved later on while performing substitution) and then matching anything till last of value. While substitution, substituting whole line value with only matched value to get desired results.

---

---

***3rd solution:*** Using GNU `grep` here. Using GNU `grep`'s `-oP` options here to enable PCRE regex engine in this program. In main program matching everything from starting to till - and forgetting that match with `\k` option of GNU `grep`. Then matching everything just before `-` and printing it.

```
grep -oP '^.*?-\K[^_]*' Input_file
```